# javascript - two js file in one file

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I have 2 js file ( main.js, work.js) and want to combine these, but I need to keep their file name so I can call work.js from main.js like

```
w = new Worker("work.js");
```

Any idea of this?

Comment: it can not be done

Comment: Follow this link it may helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/a/950146/2798643

Answer (score 0):

[minify](https://github.com/mrclay/minify) github library can be used to combine multiple js or css files  into one file when you stack them in a url like

```
          <script src="/scripts/js/work.js,/scripts/js/main.js"></script>
```